# Setting HTTP header in Joomla 4 component

Tags: joomla-4.x

In Joomla 3.10 a component could set the HTTP response status code using something like:

```
 header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 403 Not Permitted');
```

In Joomla 4.x the header is set by the component, but appears to be overwritten by Joomla. (This is demonstrated by putting an exit command at the very end of component processing). Is there a way to set the response effectively in Joomla 4?

I wanted to tag this with HTTP which is quite distinct from HTTPS, but was not permitted :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Joomla\Application\WebApplicationInterface::setHeader()`](https://api.joomla.org/framework-2/classes/Joomla-Application-WebApplicationInterface.html#method_setHeader) method implemented by the web application class. Example use in controllers:

```
$this->app->setHeader('Status', '403', true);
```

If you want, you can work directly with underlying PSR-7 response object using `getResponse()` and `setResponse()` methods:

```
$response = $this->app->getResponse();
$response = $response->withHeader('Status', '403');
$this->app->setResponse($response);
```

Comment: Thanks very much